# 3 CPU on 4 socket mobo - any gotchas?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, xeon, supermicro

got a 2U Supermicro server with 4 sockets, however only 3 are populated with Xeon E7-4830v4. Various persons advised to either remove 1 or even better add another CPU so I run an even umber of CPUs.

Can anyone hw-savvy shed some light whether running tri-CPU is a no-no or is bound to cause issues etc?

Thanks